# SELECT DISTINCT count entries within each month. MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a database with a column containing email addresses and a second column containing category and a third column containing date.

What I want to do is count the number of unique email addresses in category 'A' between multiple date ranges. So I have this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email) as counter 
FROM table 
WHERE category = "A" AND date < "2015-12" AND date > "2015-11";
```

Then I'll do a separate query for the second date range.

NOW HERE'S MY PROBLEM:

If an email address appears in month one, and also in month two it will go on the count for both months because it's unique within the range I'm querying.

How do I create a query that will count the unique email addresses for a year let's say, then count the distinct entries in a month period without including the duplicates?

Thanks!

Comment: Again confusing "unique email addresses for a year let's say" - the same email in different months of the year count as one or separately for each month? You have to explain what you need very detailed and definitely, if you want to get proper result. It's essential part of programing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want custom date you can set the value to vars

```
$custom_date_begin = "2015-01-10";
$custom_date_end  = "2015-02-10";
```

then for vars and the month group by  you can use somethings like this

```
 "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email) as counter 
 FROM table 
 WHERE category = 'A' 
 AND date >= '$custom_begin_date' AND date <='$custom_end_date'
 group by MONTH (date);"
```

Comment: The query will always return empty result, because no date can satisfy this: `date < "2015-01-01" AND date > "2015-12-31"`

Comment: Thanks for this scaisEdge! How would I do this if I wanted custom date ranges... say 2015-01-10 > 2015-02-10?

Comment: I have update the answer with vars for custom date.  if the answer is right  please mark as accepted and/or rate as useful

Answer (score 0):

Information provided is not enough for writing adequate query. So I'll try to guess details.

Lets assume that we need to count number of unique emails for each month and category.

The query could be like the following:

```
SELECT dt, category, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM (
    SELECT LEFT(`date`,7) AS dt, category, email
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY LEFT(`date`,7), category, email
) x
GROUP BY dt, category
```

If you have variable date ranges, then you'd better group on daily basis, and then count emails via script for each date range.